# PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, select, plsql

I'm developing a trigger which starts and stops services. The point is that my trigger doesn't stop the service if it first has found an error which is this:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-44303: service name exists
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVICE_ERR", line 21
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVICE", line 316
```

So to avoid receiveing an error I need to check first if the service is online and, only if it is, stop it but PL/SQL doesn't accept select into if statement. How should I do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER managed_service_start
    AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    pdb_role VARCHAR2(64);
    host VARCHAR2(64);
    pdb_name VARCHAR2(64);
    rw_service VARCHAR2(64);
    ro_service VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    SELECT database_role INTO pdb_role FROM v$database;
    SELECT host_name INTO host FROM v$instance;
    SELECT Upper(sys_context ('userenv', 'con_name')) INTO pdb_name FROM dual;
    SELECT rw_service into rw_service FROM dual;
    SELECT ro_service into ro_service FROM dual;
    IF pdb_role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
        DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(rw_service);
        IF (ro_service) IN (SELECT name FROM v$services) THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(ro_service);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- IF host IN ('host_name1','host_name2') THEN
        IF host LIKE '%de%' THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(ro_service);
            IF (rw_service) IN (SELECT name FROM v$services) THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(rw_service);
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF (ro_service) IN (SELECT name FROM v$services) THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(ro_service);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/


    LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
15/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
15/22    PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
22/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
22/23    PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
26/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
26/23    PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
```

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you're getting the values for `rw_service` and `ro_service` from, so I just hardcoded them here as an example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER managed_service_start
    AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    pdb_role VARCHAR2(64);
    host VARCHAR2(64);
    pdb_name VARCHAR2(64);
    rw_service VARCHAR2(64) := 'rw_service_name';
    ro_service VARCHAR2(64) := 'ro_service_name';
    rw_up varchar2(1);
    ro_up varchar2(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT database_role INTO pdb_role FROM v$database;
    SELECT host_name INTO host FROM v$instance;
    SELECT Upper(sys_context ('userenv', 'con_name')) INTO pdb_name FROM dual;
    -- validate that services are up. if they are down the variable will be null.
    select max('Y') into rw_up
            from v$services
            where name = rw_service;
    select max('Y') into ro_up
            from v$services
            where name = ro_service;
    IF pdb_role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
        DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(rw_service);
        IF (ro_up is not null) THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(ro_service);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- IF host IN ('host_name1','host_name2') THEN
        IF host LIKE '%de%' THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(ro_service);
            IF (rw_up is not null) THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(rw_service);
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF (ro_up is not null) THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(ro_service);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Instead of putting your query in an IF statement, put your IF logic in the query, and use the result in your IF statement.