# Update records with a select statement

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, sql-update

I have a cursor with v_emp_id & v_in_term variables. I need to assign v_in_term either yes or no values for each record based on whether or not the person is in a particular query. I'm not able to join the employees table into my cursor query. The general logic to it is like this:

```
if v_emp_id in (select emp_id from employees)  
then v_in_term := 'Yes';                        
else v_in_term := 'No'; 
end if;
```

It says I can't use a query here. How could I change this?

[Error] Compilation (906: 42): PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528585/pls-00405-subquery-not-allowed-in-this-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `IN` with a subquery (or `EXISTS`) in a PL/SQL `IF` statement. Instead, you can use `SELECT ... INTO` and either your query:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_emp_id  EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID%TYPE := 1;
  v_in_term VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN v_emp_id in (select emp_id from employees)
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
         END
  INTO   v_in_term
  FROM   DUAL;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_in_term);
END;
/
```

or `EXISTS`:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_emp_id  EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID%TYPE := 1;
  v_in_term VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employees WHERE emp_id = v_emp_id)
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
         END
  INTO   v_in_term
  FROM   DUAL;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_in_term);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ef999973abc02a86173a5e073984c553)*

Answer (score 0):

A bit more compact way is to use `count(*)`

```
declare
  v_emp_id  EMP.EMP_ID%TYPE := 2;
  v_in_term VARCHAR2(3);
begin
  select decode(count(*),0,'no','yes') into v_in_term from emp
  where emp_id = v_emp_id;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_in_term); 
end;
/
```

`count(*)` returns *zero* if no record is found in the table, which is mapped to `no` in the `decode`. All other results are mapped to `yes`, so it works even in cases you do  not check with *primary key*..